# How to fix " Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'removeVowelsAndSpaces' has already been declared " in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function

I am removing vowels and spaces in the given string. But I'm facing this issue don't know what is this.

```
let removeVowelsAndSpaces = function(givenString)
{
   // start your code here.

 var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  //givenString = String(givenString)
  //return givenString.replace(" ","")
  return givenString.replace(' ','').split('').filter(function(el) {
    return vowels.indexOf(el.toLowerCase()) == -1;
  }).join('');
};
var removeVowelsAndSpaces(`'arjit kumar'`)
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'removeVowelsAndSpaces' has already been declared. Here I have declared var for removeVowelAndSpaces but no luck. Please help

Comment: Remove the `var` from the last line, or put the result into a new variable

Comment: ```var vowelChanged = removeVowelsAndSpaces("'arjit kumar'")
alert(vowelChanged);```. I have changed it but the same error repeats

Comment: I have tried your code by `console.log(removeVowelsAndSpaces("'arjit kumar'"))` and I didn't encounter any error. I think your code works fine. I can't comment so I have to put my answer here. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks I got it. As, I'm using the same tab in the browser its showing that error. Now i checked opening in a new tab. It looks good.

Comment: So, what should i do if i want to display my output in single quotes????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is another `var` at the bottom of the code. Maybe you can use another variable for storing your result. Also you haven't used a `=` sign. This may result in a error.

Comment: I have removed the var at the bottom and tried 
```var vowelChanged = removeVowelsAndSpaces("'arjit kumar'") alert(vowelChanged);``` . Still ti gives the same error

Comment: I have tried your code. Maybe you are doing something else wrong in your code. Please don't decrease my reputation if you just are not able to fix your error.

Comment: [Use This Code. I am sure it will work](https://hastebin.com/ukeninigin.js)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `var` at the bottom, which declares the variable again. Since you have already declared the variable at the top you only need to use it. Like in the `console.log` function I am using `removeVowelsAndSpaces`.

```
   // start your code here.

   let removeVowelsAndSpaces = function(givenString){   

     let vowels = {
       'a': true,
       'e': true,
       'i': true,
       'o': true,
       'u': true,
       ' ': true,
     };

     let result = "";

     for (let i = 0; i < givenString.length; i++) {
       let letter = givenString[i].toLowerCase();
       if (!vowels[letter]) {
         result += givenString[i];
       }
     }
     return result;
   };
   console.log(removeVowelsAndSpaces("arijit kumar"))
```